# How to clear firefox's cache

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching

I'm using Firefox 73.0.1, during development I realised fx always loads an old version of a javascript file. I guess it is stored in some sort of cache.
What I tried so far:

- Clear cache (Firefox option)
- Reload (using uMatrix's "hold shift to ignore browser cache" option)
- Renaming the js file (error message: could not load)
- Deleting the js file (error message: could not load)
- Restart Firefox
- Reboot computer

Still Firefox loads the old version of the js file. The old version is not on my computer, not even as a backup.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Library Button (the button next to the download button in the menu bar)[image]

navigate to History, then Delete newest History.
There you can check "Cache" and other stuff.

---

Other method:
Go to: `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`
You should see at least one semi-randomly-named profile folder there. (If you see more than one, you'll want to figure out which one has the unwanted session history in it by checking each one.)

Double-click into the profile folder

Right-click the sessionstore-backups folder and rename it to OLDsessionstore-backups (later you can mine the files in this folder for any important tabs you want to restore)

Comment: did you try to set a longer time and check everything? Otherwise, try it with a browser you didnt use before

Comment: Yes. The whole history is deleted. For some reason it works with chrome.

Comment: try the method i added to the post